# hybris - productcockpit language not available

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Problem: Language not available in productcockpit

What I did: I assigned language to the catalog

[My Impex script used to assign Language ja, engb and nl to MyGlobal catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6XbF.png)

All languages got assigned (verified in hmc) but nl (Dutch) is not available in productcockpit

[nl (Dutch) is not available in productcockpit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aO2q.png)

Note: This works in my local hybris but when I try in test environment it gives my above reported results.

Comment: You did run an update :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. There were user restrictions. I added the language to the usergroup and I was able to see in cockpit.

Update not required

Answer (score 0):

After you perform some changes in your ImpEx files then you need to run "ant clean all" then in the platform tab  do the update in HAC. then only ImpEx files update in the HMC.